# Scala pattern matching referencing confusion inside matched value

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

```
def listMatch(list:List[Int]): Unit = list match {
  case a @ ((31 :: tail) :+ 4) => println(tail)
}

listMatch(List(31,1,2,3,4))
```

when I run above line result is "List(1, 2, 3)". 
so my question is where does tail function call refers in "println(tail)" statement ? Clearly it is not matched value because "a.tail" call gives another result.Also
if this tail call refers "list" beginning of the match statement shouldn't result needs to be "List(1, 2, 3, 4)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tail` in question is the remainder of the list after unapplying the `head`, `31`, and the last element `4`. This leaves us with a `List(1, 2, 3)` which is the result you're seeing. The binding to the value `tail` happens inside the pattern match.

We can pattern match on the list assignment itself in order to extract out the different parts:

```
scala> val list = List(31,1,2,3,4)
list: List[Int] = List(31, 1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> val ((head :: tail) :+ 4) = list
head: Int = 31
tail: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

If we remove `+:` from the unapply, we'll get the same `tail` call as `list.tail`, which evaluates to `List(1, 2, 3, 4)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here, tail is not a function, it is a local value, defined in the pattern matched. You can rewrite your example like that :

```
    def listMatch(list:List[Int]): Unit = list match {
    case a @ ((31 :: shadok) :+ 4) => println(shadok)
    }                                 //> listMatch: (list: List[Int])Unit

    listMatch(List(31,1,2,3,4))       //> List(1, 2, 3)
```